# Run PHP function only if an <a> tag has been clicked elsewhere

Tags: php

I'm teaching myself PHP. I have a PHP based CMS website where people can up or down vote content on pages. To the right of the buttons is a counter that increments up when the up arrow is pressed and down when the down arrow is pressed.

I'd like to add a timestamp next to the buttons where the time and date of the last vote are shown. If the vote buttons have never been pressed on a particular piece of content, then don't show any date. A "Freshness" feature of the vote buttons, if you will.

The vote buttons and counter are contained within a table like so:

```
<table class="rating-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo Kohana::lang('ui_main.credibility');?>:</td>
  <td><a href="javascript:rating('<?php echo $incident_id; ?>','add','original','oloader_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>')"><img id="oup_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>" src="<?php echo url::file_loc('img'); ?>media/img/up.png" alt="UP" title="UP" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:rating('<?php echo $incident_id; ?>','subtract','original')"><img id="odown_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>" src="<?php echo url::file_loc('img'); ?>media/img/down.png" alt="DOWN" title="DOWN" border="0" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="" class="rating_value" id="orating_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>"><?php echo $incident_rating; ?></a></td>
  <td><a href="" id="oloader_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>" class="rating_loading" ></a></td>

            <td class="vote_date">

                    Last voted at: 
                    <?php
                    $date = date_create();
                    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    ?> 
            </td>
```

The last `<td>` element is just me fiddling around - I have my placeholder and time format. I just need to set to only show when one of the up or down vote buttons are pressed, not just when the page loads like now.

How do I "link" the output of the date function to button clicks as opposed to just page loads? I'm aware that this could probably be done in JavaScript but since I'm learning PHP right now I'd like to try this in PHP.

Comment: you have a few options to do the click.  Personally Id go with Jquery.  Have a look at the examples in the jquery .on function here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You can execute php code without page refreshing by ajax call.on any event you can fire ajax call , that will execute your php code. and provide a response , by help of javascript you can put it in your page

Comment: Thanks for the tips I took a look at the api.jquery.com/on link. Will look into ajax too. Create the universe first right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP unlike Javascript runs before it arrives in a users browser, in other words it is executed on the server. Because of this it is not able to respond to interactions on the site by a user on its own.

**Option 1:** Add an OnClick() event to the anchored link to execute a JS Function and do output time in JS.

**Option 2:** Use a JS Event on the link or create a JS or jQuery function that executes on button click. Then use AJAX to make a call to the server to execute a PHP function to get the current time and date.

Option 2 is your best bet if you are determined to do it in PHP and the jQuery library makes using AJAX functions pretty easy. But it would be easiest just doing it in JS or jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nice answer.  The OP needs to be aware of the difference between a server-side language and a client-side language and how the server and client/user interact.

Comment: Thanks for the info I will attempt option 1 as per your recommendation. My confusion though is that I can add onClick() to the  2nd and 3rd td a elements (the up/down anchor element vote buttons). But, how would I then direct the output of the onClick() to the last td element? In my mind the output would effect the existing element, it should output ina  different element

Comment: You can use JS to remove or replace the last element. There are a few ways to do this this simplist way would be to create two <a> links in the last td and give each one its own ID, then use CSS to display the one the would click on and use JS to change the CSS to hide the first one and display the second <a> with the onCLick event. Be sure to execute the JS code for the datetime before you display the <a> link though