# Display when the last visitor upvoted or downvoted next to the vote buttons

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP based CMS website. People have the ability to up or down vote a piece of content. I [previously inquired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148459/php-beginner-running-php-funtion-only-if-an-a-tag-has-been-clicked-elsewhere) as to how to add a time stamp to the vote buttons so that a person can see how recently anyone else has voted on the content.

I currently have the following table:

```
<table class="rating-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo Kohana::lang('ui_main.credibility');?>:</td>
        <td><a onclick="myFunction()" href="javascript:rating('<?php echo $incident_id; ?>','add','original','oloader_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>')"><img id="oup_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>" src="<?php echo url::file_loc('img'); ?>media/img/up.png" alt="UP" title="UP" border="0" /></a></td>
        <td><a onclick="myFunction()" href="javascript:rating('<?php echo $incident_id; ?>','subtract','original')"><img id="odown_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>" src="<?php echo url::file_loc('img'); ?>media/img/down.png" alt="DOWN" title="DOWN" border="0" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="" class="rating_value" id="orating_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>"><?php echo $incident_rating; ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="" id="oloader_<?php echo $incident_id; ?>" class="rating_loading" ></a></td>
        <td>Last voted at:

                    <span id="vote_date">
                    <script>
                    function myFunction()
                    {
                    var d = new Date();
                    var x = document.getElementById("vote_date");
                    x.innerHTML=Date();
                    }
                    </script>
                    </span>

        </td>



      </tr>
    </table>
```

The second and third `<td>` elements are the up and down vote buttons. When someone clicks them the time and date is displayed in the last `<td>` element. Great!

Except (beginner here) I need this to not be session specific. If someone else visits the page the next day, they should see the last time that someone interacted with the vote buttons.

I do have limited coding skills but I suspect that I must somehow store the output of `myFunction` in a table and then echo it when someone else visits the page - is that right? Is there a simpler way?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do on the live site. The time that the last person voted should be displayed next to the vote buttons (code block above is only on localhost): http://tinyurl.com/k5w4olu

Comment: Yes, you'll need a database for this. Sessions are just per-user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track you need to add the date into a database or memory. the best way would be to AJAX the date variable to a mySQL db that you have setup and connected via PHP.

To understand more about mySQL go here -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

You will need to use AJAX easiest way is the jQuery Library -> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Answer (score 2):

you must store the votes in a database.

when the page loads, get the vote value for the particular page that is loading, and programmatically show an up or a downvote based on what the database says.